# How to deal with combat immediately after entering room through narrow passage

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, movement

On the first dungeon in my campaign, most rooms have enemies spread throughout them, and as soon as players enter the room, the player heading the party is spotted and combat begins. But said player at the front is blocking the hallway and in almost every case he never gets a chance to move forward and let the others through, causing complaints.

Is there a rule to prevent this, am I starting combat too early, or is there another problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, there's a rule that prevents this from being a problem. From [Movement, Position, and Distance](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/movementPositionAndDistance.htm#friend):

> You can move through a square occupied by a friendly character, unless you are charging. When you move through a square occupied by a friendly character, that character doesn’t provide you with cover.

(There's no movement restrictions to this: it's not difficult terrain or anything of the like, and no squeezing is required, as for moving past an opponent. It's just moving through a five-foot square.)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to stop some one from blocking the entrance is to make 15ft/3 squares wide and make the tunnels 15ft/3 squares wide as well. Also make sure the monsters are away from the door again 15ft/3 squares away.